# Wix on windows 10 with mvs2013 or mvs2014 is not working (making php executable)

Tags: msbuild, wix

Wix on windows 10 with mvs2013 or mvs2014 is not working.

I am getting the error:
Error        `The "GenerateCompileWithObjectPath" task could not be loaded from the assembly \WixTasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\WixTasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.    SetupProject5    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets`

If i try to include `WixTasks.dll` to the project, when mvs2013 or mvs2014 crashes during the build. I include `\WixTasks.dll` to the  `C:\SourceControl\vs2015\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj` from the unpacked wix binaries folder:
`C:\SourceControl`

// `C:\SourceControl\vs2015\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>3.10</ProductVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>0adbe89f-e1ce-4345-90e6-64b8304fa42f</ProjectGuid>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputName>SetupProject1</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
     <WixToolPath>C:\SourceControl</WixToolPath>
    <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)\wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)\WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>    
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
  <!--
    To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
    Other similar extension points exist, see Wix.targets.
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    </Target>
    -->
```

I was reading different online forums and examples the last two days. Also Pact books on wix by Nick Ramirez. Nothing is working.

Comment: Please use proper names when possible, it makes it easier to understand what you are talking about - I assume you mean VS2013 and VS2015, not 'mvs2013' and 'mvs2014'?

Answer (score 2):

Define the following MSBuild variables and everything should work.

```
<WixRootPath Condition=" '$(WixRootPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Tools\wix\$(WixTargetVersion)\</WixRootPath>
<WixToolPath Condition=" '$(WixToolPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)</WixToolPath>
<WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
<WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)sdk\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
<WixTasksPath Condition=" '$(WixTasksPath)' == '' ">$(WixToolPath)WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
<WixSdkPath Condition=" '$(WixSdkPath)' == '' ">$(WixRootPath)sdk\</WixSdkPath>
```

Just make sure the paths are right. These paths are for the wix 3.10.2 binaries which I checkout for my builds on the build machine.

I think the build tasks should be looking in the path defined by the WIX environment variable but I'm not 100% sure about that.

I *think* defining all the variables with the path you set should fix everything since the error mentions looking in C:\WixTasks.dll normally the path it looks for is something like $(WixInstallPath)WixTasks.dll but if $(WixInstallPath) isn't properly defined it will just be empty and default to C:\WixTasks.dll. You do define $(WixTasksPath) but I think it's getting overwritten for somereason...

Regardless, there's something wrong on your system right now but you can work around it this way probably.

---

EDIT: If the above doesn't work, download the wix binaries from [here](https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/619491) and extract them into a folder called "Wix" or whatever you want to call it. Then set your WixRootPath to be equal to that location.

Comment: I did as you said. Visual studio crashes. I am also getting more than 100 warnings of type:  "The global element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/*' has already been declared".

Comment: I have tried on vs2013 and vs2015. Which vs do you use? Which wix do you install? How do you build? Do you use visual studio?

Comment: I am sorry, i am new to exetutables, etc.. . Seems the error is that i should uninstall wix, and use binaries with MSBuild Tools instead.

Comment: MSBuild give a lot of errors, ot type "*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio", for example:   C:\SourceControl\own\box1\Tools\wix\candle.exe -dDebug -d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*" . Could you please give me a full eample of *.wixproj file

Comment: Dear Brian, if you could give me any full (the more complicated, the better. I am trying to make executable for phpbrowserbox website: https://github.com/dhtml/phpbrowserbox ) *.wixproj example i would appreciate a lot. Seems i use some variables, which MSBuild does not understand.

Comment: Sorry I just checked this now, we live in different parts of the world. Unfortunately this didn't fix your issue.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong on your end you can try runing devenv /setup and reinstalling wix. You should be able to follow the wix tutorial https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/ to at least get a simple build running from visual studio. I am using vs2013 fyi.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when using VS2015 and working on git branches that use different versions of Wix. (I'm upgrading to the latest Wix version but not all branches are there yet.)

You must terminate and restart VS if you switch between git branches that use different versions if Wix.  VS holds some Wix files open, files that won't work under any other version of Wix.  If you forget to do this your VS build will fail with the (quite cryptic) message of "The "GenerateCompileWithObjectPath" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\WixTasks.dll"

Comment: Exactly what I ran into today, but with VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution from [WiX Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/Web%20Development/9781784393212/1/ch01lvl1sec13/Building%20a%20WiX%20installer%20from%20the%20command%20line) by Nick Ramirez, 2015, Chapter1 "Building a WiX installer from the command line", Example 4 "BuildMachineInstaller"

Download and unzip wix binaries file, for example from [here](https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/619491).
1. Create some folder for your project, for example `C:\SourceControl\own\box1` with file `Product.wxs`
2. Extract binaries to some folder, for example to `C:\SourceControl\own\box1\tools\wix`
3. start windows command line tool `cmd` and change to your project folder. Execute `candle` and `light` commands as folows:

C:\SourceControl\own\box1>`C:\SourceControl\own\box1\tools\wix\candle *.wxs -o obj\`

C:\SourceControl\own\box1>`C:\SourceControl\own\box1\tools\wix\light obj\*.wixobj -o bin\CommandLineInstaller.msi`

Anyway, if somebody could give some working example files and description how to make *.exe or *.msi with MSBuild or Visual Studio Build and wix, i would appreciate a lot. The other examples in Pact books are not working by pure copying, although are very useful for general understanding.

Comment: other working ways to make windows *.msi or *.exe files include:  [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and [IExpress](http://ss64.com/nt/iexpress.html)
[link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/iexpress-2-0-and-command-line-switches)
  [link](https://www.egroup-us.com/2011/11/iexpress-windows-compression-tool-for-self-extracting-files/)
[link](https://kb.tanium.com/IExpress)

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this issue and found that at the top of the wix2010.targets file was the following property group.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<WixInstallPath Condition=" '$(WixInstallPath)' == ''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Installer XML\3.11@InstallRoot)</WixInstallPath>
<WixInstallPath Condition=" '$(WixInstallPath)' == ''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Installer XML\3.11@InstallRoot)</WixInstallPath>
```

When checking the referenced registry path there was no entry for 3.11 but there was one there for 3.10. and the installed version was reported as 3.10. So updating the property group to the following corrected the issue for me.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<WixInstallPath Condition=" '$(WixInstallPath)' == ''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Installer XML\3.10@InstallRoot)</WixInstallPath>
<WixInstallPath Condition=" '$(WixInstallPath)' == ''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Installer XML\3.10@InstallRoot)</WixInstallPath>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following these instructions:

Download WIX311.exe from https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3111rtm
Download Votive2017.vsix from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension

Remove any old WiX nuget packets from your solution/project

Follow these instructions (you can omit /quiet).

http://packagingstuffs.blogspot.com/2017/11/wix-toolset-311-silent-install-method.html
Content from the website above;

To Install:
Step1: Download the source from web and get the installer wix311.exe.
Step2: Run following command:wix311.exe /install /quiet /norestart
Step 3: Copy the Votive2017.vsix file (provided by vendor) to the local machine (e.g. %TEMP%)
Step 4: Run VSIXinstaller from its stored location
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe"  /quiet

Good luck and best regards